# Thumbnail Look For WP

Tags: thumbnails

I would refer you to this site:

http://jimmyscarff.org/2013/11/12/the-funness-of-victor-harbor/

I am trying to get medium size photos for the pics, but they are all thumbnails and not WYSIWYG as I see them on my posts page.

It looks really sucky, so how do I change the size of the pics so they are in medium size like the size of the Featured image, as the first photo is, and NOT THUMBNAIL SIZED. I am stumped to know as to what I have done wrong, and I want it looking good for my blog.

Comment: Please **edit your question** to include the actual code used to output the images in question.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size

just create your own image size you want to best fit your website.

you could then use this plugin to regenerate all your thumbnails.

http://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/

Comment: That went way over my head. I know very little about coding, and I don't think my theme is based on a child theme, so when they are updated I lose the code. functions.php sounds like fun, but I don't know how to edit that stuff. I have installed your plugin, and made some adjustments based on other advice, but I can't figure out what I did wrong in the first place to get it looking like that. I have made other posts where pics and captionsa re completely the way I want them.